# JavaScript `reduce` to Ruby `reduce`

Tags: ruby, reduce

In JavaScript a `reduce` function may look like:

```js
array.reduce((acc, cur, idx, arr) => {
    // body
}, starting_value);
```

I'm trying to somehow have that `arr` argument, which is a copy of the original array, I've seen it being useful plenty of times. This is as far as I could take it:

```rb
array.each_with_index.reduce (starting_value) do |acc (cur, idx)|
    # body
end
```

I've been browsing through the Ruby documentation for quite some time (I actually copied the `.each_with_index` since I found it somewhere), looking for anything even remotely like what I've been looking for.

To be quite honest functionally I could split it into multiple lines and store something in a variable, but if I can keep my functional approach in JavaScript with Ruby, I would be super happy.

In essence: is there any way to get the `arr` parameter within the body?

Comment: The question is about Ruby, please don't tag [tag:javascript], even though you mention it in the context of the question. The question isn't relevant to people following the [tag:javascript] tag.

Comment: Also: `reduce` was added to JavaScript in ES5, not ES2015 ("ES6").

Comment: _"which is a copy of the original array"_ – that's not a copy. In JavaScript's `reduce`, the 4th argument is a reference to the array itself. In your Ruby example, you can refer to it via `array`.

Comment: @Stefan Well ofc you CAN do that in this example, but after chaining the array with 5 or 6 other maps/filters/reduces or if this specific reduce is nested, then you have to start adding a bunch of small variables and you loose the readability of these functions being chained, instead you you have 8 lines of code which are formatted all the same because they are all variable declarations

Comment: `array.each_with_index.with_object(array).reduce(initial) { |acc, ((cur, idx) arr)| ... }` would work but I doubt that it's more readable. In Ruby, `reduce` is defined in `Enumerable`, not `Array`. It's solely based on `each` yielding elements – the underlying collection (if any) is not being tracked.

Comment: @Stefan but what i mean is, let's say that you `array.filter.reduce`, in this case you can't do `.with_object(array)` because it is not `array` that you want as `arr` but `array.filter`. In this case you would have to save `array.filter` in a temporary variable before moving on to `reduce`, is that what you are saying? (PS I kew about `with_object` but as discussed above, i thought it wasn't the right tool)

Comment: More or less, yes. You could use `array.filter.then { |arr| arr.reduce { ... } }` to limit the variable's scope to the block.

Comment: @Stefan alright, thank you very much! feel free to leave it as answer if you wish :D you were a great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reduce` – being an `Enumerable` method – is not aware of the collection it is enumerating.

You have to incorporate the array yourself, for example via `then` / `yield_self`:

```
[1, 2, 3].then do |arr|
  arr.each_with_index.reduce(4) do |acc, (cur, idx)|
    p acc: acc, cur: cur, idx: idx, arr: arr
    acc + cur
  end
end
# {:acc=>4, :cur=>1, :idx=>0, :arr=>[1, 2, 3]}
# {:acc=>5, :cur=>2, :idx=>1, :arr=>[1, 2, 3]}
# {:acc=>7, :cur=>3, :idx=>2, :arr=>[1, 2, 3]}
#=> 10
```

or somewhere within the chain:

```
[1, 2, 3].then do |arr|
  arr.map { |x| x * 2 }.then do |arr_2|
    arr_2.each_with_index.reduce(4) do |acc, (cur, idx)|
      p acc: acc, cur: cur, idx: idx, arr: arr, arr_2: arr_2
      acc + cur
    end
  end
end
# {:acc=>4, :cur=>2, :idx=>0, :arr=>[1, 2, 3], :arr_2=>[2, 4, 6]}
# {:acc=>6, :cur=>4, :idx=>1, :arr=>[1, 2, 3], :arr_2=>[2, 4, 6]}
# {:acc=>10, :cur=>6, :idx=>2, :arr=>[1, 2, 3], :arr_2=>[2, 4, 6]}
#=> 16
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create a custom `reduce` method:

```
module Enumerable
  def reduce_with_self(initial_or_sym, sym = nil)
    if initial_or_sym.is_a?(Symbol)
      operator = initial_or_sym
      initial = nil
    else
      initial = initial_or_sym
      operator = sym
    end
    accumulator = initial
    each_with_index do |item, index|
      if index.zero? && initial.nil?
        accumulator = item
        next
      end
      accumulator = operator.nil? ? yield(accumulator, item, self) : accumulator.send(operator, item)
    end
    accumulator
  end
end
```

The third argument of the block will be a reference to a collection:

```
> [1,2,3,4].reduce_with_self(0) do |acc, item, array|
>   p array
>   acc += item
> end
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
 => 10

> [1,2,3,4].reduce_with_self(2,:+)
 => 12 

> [1,2,3,4].reduce_with_self(:+)
 => 10
```

Of course, this implementation will be slower than the original one:

```
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report('reduce') { 1000.times { (0..10000).reduce(0) { |acc, item| acc += item } } }
  x.report('reduce_with_self') { 1000.times { (0..10000).reduce_with_self(0) { |acc, item, array| acc += item } } }
end

       user     system      total        real
reduce  0.501833   0.000000   0.501833 (  0.502698)
reduce_with_self  0.955978   0.000000   0.955978 (  0.956809)
```